# How to use SSL on RabbitMQ with Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, ssl, rabbitmq

I'm running a RabbitMQ instance on Docker with this docker-compose.yml and no problem, it' working:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  my-rabbit:
    image: imageAddress
    hostname: my-rabbit
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - testNetwork
networks:
  testNetwork:
    external: true
```

But I have to use that RabbitMQ with certificates to get connection over TLS.

I tried this way and certs folder contains certificates but got error:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  my-rabbit:
    tty: true
    image: imageAddress
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE=/cert_rabbitmq/testca/cacert.pem
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE=/cert_rabbitmq/server/cert.pem
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_CACERTFILE=/cert_rabbitmq/server/key.pem
    hostname: my-rabbit
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - /home/ilkaygunel/Desktop/certs:/cert_rabbitmq
    networks:
      - testNetwork
networks:
  testNetwork:
    external: true
```

The error is like below. It says old-style configuration file exists but I don't know what to do.

```
my-rabbit_1  | error: Docker configuration environment variables specified, but old-style (Erlang syntax) configuration file '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config' exists
my-rabbit_1  |   Suggested fixes: (choose one)
my-rabbit_1  |    - remove '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config'
my-rabbit_1  |    - remove any Docker-specific 'RABBITMQ_...' environment variables
my-rabbit_1  |    - convert '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config' to the newer sysctl format ('/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf'); see https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file
```

What should I do to use that certificate files?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `RABBITMQ_SSL*` envs are deprecated, this solution worked for me, create [your own certificates](https://gist.github.com/achesco/b893fb55b90651cf5f4cc803b78e19fd) and `rabbitmq.conf` which contains TLS configurations like this:

**dir structure:**

```
├── certs
│   ├── rabbitmq.conf
│   ├── root.crt
│   ├── server.crt
│   └── server.key
├── data
│   └── # rmq data and other stuff
└── docker-compose.yml
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  tls-rabbitmq:
    hostname: 'tls-dev.rmq'
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'tls-rmq-dev'
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rmq-test
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=Wg1-U5hP8xEYY_zfMPFEb5l-HvrsH
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
      - "tls-dev.rmq:192.168.166.6"
    ports:
        - "5672:5671"   # forced TLS AMQP
        - "15672:15672" # http panel
        - "15692:15692" # metrics
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ./certs/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:ro
      - ./certs/root.crt:/etc/ssl/rmq-cacert.pem:ro
      - ./certs/server.crt:/etc/ssl/rmq-cert.pem:ro
      - ./certs/server.key:/etc/ssl/rmq-key.pem:ro
```

`rabbitmq.conf`

```
listeners.tcp                    = none
listeners.ssl.default            = 5671
ssl_options.cacertfile           = /etc/ssl/rmq-cacert.pem
ssl_options.certfile             = /etc/ssl/rmq-cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile              = /etc/ssl/rmq-key.pem
ssl_options.verify               = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = true
ssl_options.versions.1           = tlsv1.2
ssl_options.honor_cipher_order   = true
ssl_options.honor_ecc_order      = true
```

at the end, `docker-compose up -d` and you good to go.

P.S: remember to add `tls-dev.rmq` address to your `/etc/hosts` and pass server IP address, connect to your rabbitmq with your **client certificate**.

Comment: hi have been struggle for two days , what is the /etc/ssl located in the rabbitmq.conf ?

Comment: I have a directory called `certs` along docker-compose.yml file and I mount my tls files inside RabbitMQ container.

Comment: problem of mine is the container cannot read the location of the cert file of rabbitmq.conf , i need to use Dockerfile to copy the cert , but i wanna to do in a one Single Docker Compose file without using Dockerfile, are you doing this?

Comment: Could you please send your code on GitHub or something and explain your scenario and I'll fix it for you.
or you could try this on your Dockerfile:
COPY ./rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use an image with rabbitmq of version before 3.7.0 where an old-style config file [used by default](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file-formats).

If there is an option you might want to upgrade a version of your rabbitmq image to newer one. Newer versions of images work with new ini-styled config files. This upgrade is a sort of third suggestion from your error message: "convert '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config' to the newer sysctl format".

Another point. When you specify "RABBITMQ_SSL_..."-variables, rabbitmq opens a port 5671 which is tls-powered; 5672 opens as well but without tls. This behaviour might be changed with conf-file.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this. Also it seems like you are pointing the wrong files. certfile should be `cert.pem`, keyfile should be `key.pem` and cacertfile should be `cacert`

Or if you wanna use 3.7 like yours, it should be :-

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  my-rabbit:
    tty: true
    image: imageAddress
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE=/cert_rabbitmq/testca/cert.pem
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE=/cert_rabbitmq/server/key.pem
      - RABBITMQ_SSL_CACERTFILE=/cert_rabbitmq/server/cacert.pem
    hostname: my-rabbit
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - /home/ilkaygunel/Desktop/certs:/cert_rabbitmq
    networks:
      - testNetwork
networks:
  testNetwork:
    external: true
```

OR alternatively, just set up a rabbitmq config file using the new format like this :-

```
#A new style format snippet. This format is used by rabbitmq.conf files.
ssl_options.cacertfile           = /path/to/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile             = /path/to/server_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile              = /path/to/server_key.pem
ssl_options.verify               = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = true
```

Looks like from the docs, using this config format, you might not even need to use the RABBITMQ... style environment variables in your docker compose file.

Comment: I tried version 3.7 but still gives same error.

Comment: @İlkayGunel Can you please paste your rabbitmq config file?